# Changing a Desired Range

Tags: excel, vba

I am a novice to vba and would really value direction on getting around this current road block.  I would like to run a `Vlookup` for a selected range. The `Vlookup` will reference data that is updated every day.

1. Day 1, I would like for the `Vlookup` to return a value in each cell of the selected `Range ("B2:B4")`.
2. Day 2, the referenced data will change and I would like for the selected range to move one column to the right `Range("C2:C4")`.

I would like to make sure each time I run the macro, the range moves one column to the right in order to compare the change in data from one day to the next.

I have provided the code below, which allows me to run a `Vlookup` in `Range("B2:B4")` but I have yet to figure out how to change the range based upon the next empty column.

That said, thank you very much for the help, which is very much appreciated.

```
Sub FillinBlanks()
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("b2:b4")

    For Each cell In rng
        If IsEmpty(cell) Then
            cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(Sheet2!rc1,Sheet1!r5c6:r1000c8,3,false)"
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is find the last column in row 2 and simple add `1` to it. I am assuming that row 1 has headers and hence I am trying to find last column in row 2.

See this example.

```
Sub FillinBlanks()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim lCol As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        '~~> Find the last column in row 2
        lCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

        '~~> Construct your range
        Set rng = .Range(ReturnName(lCol) & "2:" & ReturnName(lCol) & "4")
    End With

    For Each cell In rng
        If IsEmpty(cell) Then
            cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(Sheet2!rc1,Sheet1!r5c6:r1000c8,3,false)"
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub

'~~> Function to return column name from column number
Function ReturnName(ByVal num As Integer) As String
    ReturnName = Split(Cells(, num).Address, "$")(1)
End Function
```

Comment: Would you happen to know how to hard code each range once the vlookup has filled in the selected range?  As of now, upon running a new vlookup based upon changed referenced data, prior ranges are changing based upon the new data given they have not been hard coded and still reference the data based upon the vlookup formula.  Once a vlookup has filled the range, I would like to hard code the range so  that data in this range does not change based upon new, referenced data. Thank you very much for the help and direction.

Comment: Do you mean to say the col B data should not change when the data in the range changes next day?

Comment: If yes, then add this line `Columns(lCol).Value = Columns(lCol).Value` before the line `End Sub`

Comment: My apologies for not being clear.  Say on Monday, we run the vlookup for range (b2:b4).  Range (b2:b4) refers to the data on Monday.  On Tuesday, we run the vlookup for range (c2:c4), which refers to the data on Tuesday.  Currently, when we run the data, range (b2:b4) will initially refer to Monday.  Then, we run the data for range (c2:c4), which refers to Tuesday and, in result, range (b2:b4) data, which referenced Monday, will now reference Tuesday as well.  It would a great help if range (b2:b4) was hard-coded and always reflected Monday's data. - Much thanks again!